# Agregar algún efecto en la transición entre carga de imágenes desde un array

Tags: javascript

Encontré un código que hace un random de imágenes en JavaScript a determinados segundos, todo está muy bien.. Sólo que ¿se podría poner algún efecto entre imágenes? intento que no se haga el cambio tan brusco y seco

Aquí el código:

```js
var imagenes=new Array(
  'http://lorempixel.com/500/200/cats',
  'http://lorempixel.com/500/200/people',
  'http://lorempixel.com/500/200/nature'
);

/**
 * Funcion para cambiar la imagen
 */
function rotarImagenes()
{
  // obtenemos un numero aleatorio entre 0 y la cantidad de imagenes que hay
  var index=Math.floor((Math.random()*imagenes.length));

  // cambiamos la imagen
  document.getElementById("imagen").src=imagenes[index];
}

/**
 * Función que se ejecuta una vez cargada la página
 */
onload=function()
{
  // Cargamos una imagen aleatoria
  rotarImagenes();

  // Indicamos que cada 5 segundos cambie la imagen
  setInterval(rotarImagenes,5000);
}
```

```html
<img id="imagen" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrias usar jquery para realizar el efecto

```js
var imagenes=new Array(
  'http://lorempixel.com/500/200/cats',
  'http://lorempixel.com/500/200/people',
  'http://lorempixel.com/500/200/nature'
);


function rotarImagenes()
{

  var index=Math.floor((Math.random()*imagenes.length));

  $("#imagen").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).attr('src',imagenes[index]);
        }).fadeIn(1000);
}

$(function(){
  
  rotarImagenes();

  setInterval(rotarImagenes,5000);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="imagen" />
```

Estarias usando el `fadeOut()` y `fadeIn()` para aplicar el efecto.

Ademas ya que tendrias jquery usa el

```
$(function() {
  ...
});
```

para detectar cuando el DOM del html esta listo

[jQuery Change Image src with Fade Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979418/jquery-change-image-src-with-fade-effect)